# Concerned about not seeing my programming language in my new job

Tags: work-environment, recruitment, mistakes

So I started a new job and so far I am seeing Java programming for developing REST APIs, but I haven't seen any JavaScript yet, which is what I was hired for.

I looked at the initial email I got from the recruiter and sure enough it says, "I am reaching out because you look to be a good fit for a Javascript/SDK Developer position I am currently supporting."

And again in the second paragraph: "An ideal candidate would be someone who has extensive experience with Javascript and JSON frameworks."

But so far the little bit of code I have seen from one of the teams is Java. And I asked a colleague, are some of these API servers being put together using Express? And he did not know what Express is.

When asked about my experience, I shared how I developed One Time Password authentication system in React Native.

At no point during the interview did anyone ask, so what about Java, are you good with that?

It could just be that this one team uses Java, I don't know for sure.

Actually, thinking back to the interview, they did know I was coming in as a Javascript developer because they asked me during the interview whether I thought React or Angular was better.

So I am concerned now. What should I do? Meaning, how do I have this discussion with my boss?

Comment: Was your programming language discussed during any of your interviews?

Comment: @sf02, I will clarify that in the OP.

Comment: Did you actually talk to anyone in the technical team during your interviews? Did you not discuss the work?

Comment: what is the real problem you are trying to solve? is your work different from what you expected?

Comment: @SethR, we did, yes what I would be doing was discussed.

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica, yeah good question. I have been wanting to see some examples of previous work put together in what I assume would be in the Express framework. So far I have just seen API documentation, you know, the Path, Method, Body, but no examples of another JS developer putting these together in the past. So either I am one of the first or...Because the only other work I have seen is from an offshore team working in Java.

Comment: how long have you been in your current job? still missing real-world solveable problem, even though i am sympathetic in general

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica, this contract just started. I guess my concern is that they were actually looking for a "Java" developer, even though all the documentation and conversations demonstrate understanding that they hired a javascript developer

Comment: so, two days? or two weeks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108259/discussion-between-daniel-and-aaaaa-says-reinstate-monica).

Comment: Things recruiters say often do not match the actual requirements and responsibilities. This is what interviews are for.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, right, thanks, it was more technical question, how do I discuss it. 520 says Reinstate Monica provided the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I realize that over the years, my questions have been very soft skills related and as a result misunderstood. How to have this conversation and so on, but for most its like, what is the problem? Just do x. Yes I get that part, but thats a soft skill, "how" do I do x. What do I say exactly? That sort of thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is entirely possible that the hiring managers got confused between Java and JavaScript and didn't consult anyone technical that would have corrected this. Managers are generally not technical people; They are paid to manage people, and that level of technical know-how is often considered a bonus-but-not-necessary skill for those managing technical teams. Good managers typically are aware of their limits and would run it by someone more technical first, but this is not always the case.

It is also possible that they are looking to include things which require client-side processing into their web applications and did not need a JavaScript person before.

The only way to know is to ask your manager how your knowledge of JavaScript fits in with the work they want you to do and their overall plan.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is a login screen that they are developing in ReactJS, but I am not working on that. I will be working on some API integrations and all the RESTful stuff I have seen thus far has been in Java. At any rate, my question and your answer on how to resolve this has diffused my anxiety over the issue and I will be posing the question to them today.

Comment: So I asked the question and apparently, the security system we are implementing is using its own programming language that is based off of Javascript and since nobody in the company is a Javascript developer, they needed someone with my background. Although, it also uses some syntax such as stabby lambdas which is not Javascript, more like Ruby, but anyway, problem solved. Thanks again.

Comment: @Daniel *"its own programming language based off of Javascript"*... That's a bit of a ref flag in my book, especially with the bit of *"syntax such as stabby lambdas which is more like Ruby"*. I'd recommend keep an eye out on whether this custom language will start giving you grief and, if it does, make sure you raise that with your manager early and often.

Comment: Ability to learn a custom corporate programming language is a valuable skill (to be mentioned on your resume). Ability to design and implement a domain specific language is even more valuable. Consider asking permission to publish conference papers on it.

Comment: @filbranden, thank you for your valuable feedback. One question I had from week one is how do I check for errors with this language? Nothing in the reference guide about it and I have yet to ask because I do not think they even know the answer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, thank you for your valuable feedback.